# Using wsdl.exe output interface file with myPage.aspx.vb - Cannot reference interface or Web Reference

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I am creating a webpage that needs to use a webservice wsdl at a remote url (https://sitename/ws/general.asmx)

I added the webservice to the project folder as generalWS (right click in VS2010, add Web service) and the editor recognizes the webservice methods.

I then used wsdl.exe to create the proxy file general.vb, which has partial classes and an interface, and copied it into my project folder.

Im now trying to reference this webservice by creating a new object for the webservice, but it does not compile:
BC30002: Type 'GeneralWS.general' is not defined.

Can someone guide me in the right direction?
Do I need to reference the interface file in the aspx.vb file?
Do I need to do something special with the web.config file?

Thanks!

Deploying on IIS6.0 with .NET Framework 2.0
Using MS Visual Studio 2010

**myPage.aspx.vb**

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.IO

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    'declare the web services
    Public wsg As New generalWS.general() ''ERROR COMPILE LINE''

    '
    '
    '
    '
```

**generalWS.vb**

```
Public Interface generalSoap
    Function1
    Function2
    '
    '
Public Partial class method1
Public Partial class method2
Public Partial class method3
```

Comment: What's this general.vb you're creating? Also, is there a reason you didn't use "Add Service Reference"?

Comment: After much googling, I thought I needed to create a proxy file using wsdl.exe via the command line, which generates a .VB file based on the link to the wsdl file on the web.

Comment: If this is not the case, it would be great.

Comment: Sorry for the multiple replies.... Should I be adding a Service Reference instead?

Comment: No, this is what "Add Web Reference" does. However, you should be using "Add Service Reference". Web References use the legacy ASMX technology and should not be used for new development.

Comment: Ahhh.. Although Im using VS2010, I set my project to build for the .NET 2.0 Framework, and now I only see 'Add Reference' and 'Add Web Reference'

Comment: Ok, that's correct. Just about the only reason to still use ASMX is if you're stuck on .NET 2.0 or below. You really should upgrade to .NET 3.5, which is simply .NET 2.0 SP2 plus some new assemblies.

Comment: On the server, Add/Remove Programs has 3.5 listed. However, IIS says 2.0 - Can I program for 3.5 in this case?

Comment: Still getting - Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'generalWS.generalSoapClient' is not defined.

Comment: So everything is working great now when I run this from my local machine (Right click aspx file, View in Browser)... No errors and my web service functions work correctly.

Comment: However, when i copy the same code to my server running ASP.NET 2.0, i get the above mentioned error

Comment: You will need to install .NET 3.5 on the server. However, it's expected that it will appear as ASP.NET 2.0 on the server. As I said, .NET 3.5 is just .NET 2.0 SP2 plus some extra stuff. The version number of ASP.NET hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using "Add Web Reference" within Visual Studio, I used "Add Service Reference".

On the server side, I upgraded to .NET 3.5